# magento add wysywyg editor in frontend page

Tags: php, javascript, magento, editor, wysiwyg

i create a module in my magento, where users can write comments and i want to add a wysiwyg editor with the most common options, but i don't know where to start, maybe the most simple example

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's a build in wysiwyg editor within magento.  Here is the forum post that shows how to activate it:
[magento wysiwyg](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/40062/)

Comment: thanks for the response, i was able to add the editor, but how can i submit the text now?

Comment: which wysiwyg are you using?  have you try to submit the installed wysiwyg?

Comment: i've installed tiny_mce, but i want to submit it with ajax

Comment: i am not very familiar with tiny_mce on magento. this might be a whole another question to ask on SO. altho i know you can integrate ajax with magento http://subesh.com.np/2010/08/working-ajax-json-objects-magento-case-ajax-powered-login-functionality/

Comment: man I can hardly tell your guys' userids apart! too many Ks, 1s, and 2s! :)